# Арифметические операторы в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Никак не могу найти арифметические операторы. Для того же BIGINT.

Нашел вот такое
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/arithmetic-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Но

> Операторы (+) и (–) можно также использовать для выполнения
>   арифметических операций со значениями типов datetime и smalldatetime.

Вкратце, нужен оператор с помощью которого можно будет сложить два числа (функция +).
Можно не на запись, а просто на вывод (результат).

Спасибо.

Comment: ответ на ваш вопрос тут https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html

Comment: *Нашел вот такое* Это не для MySQL. См. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html